# JAVA_HOME Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when using the command **flutter doctor --android-licenses**

**ERROR**: **JAVA_HOME** is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your **environment** to match the
location of your Java installation.

---

I did everything needed and the problem was not solved
Anyone here for help?

Comment: did you close the command window you were running doctor in and open a new windows and see what JAVA_HOME shows?

Comment: @OldProgrammer no